# possibly duplicate tags `canonicalization` and `canonical-link`

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, tags, tag-synonyms

I suggest combining tags [canonicalization](/questions/tagged/canonicalization) and [canonical-link](/questions/tagged/canonical-link)

Also there is another one: [canonical](/questions/tagged/canonical). It's different though. However, it might be confused with the aforementioned two. Maybe it should be renamed into `canonical answer` as per [its wiki](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/canonical/info).

[image: canonical tags]

Comment: Those tags shouldn't even exist.  [tag:canonical] is a meta tag, per [this blog post](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2010/08/the-death-of-meta-tags/)

Comment: @RobertHarvey, see my answer.

Comment: @Geo, job done (what I could do), see the edit to my answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[canonical-link](/questions/tagged/canonical-link) is an appropriate tag for its use.

[Canonicalization](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Canonicalization) (c14n) is specific computer science term that should stay its own tag.  I've added a tag-wiki (could be done better) to it.

Robert is right that the tag-wiki entry for [canonical](/questions/tagged/canonical) shows it to be a meta-tag.  I imagine someone is using that to try and label canonical answers, like this [latest question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165127/link-exact-duplicates-to-a-single-reference-question) talks about.  Since there is no process for that yet, it going to be arbitrary, but maybe **the Team needs to make a decision** on how to handle "canonical" answers before we get rid of it.

**EDIT:**  I've gone through [canonical](/questions/tagged/canonical) and most of the ones I fixed were about the URL tag (or pages), so I've retagged them [canonical-link](/questions/tagged/canonical-link).  There have been a few that shouldn't have had the tag for any reason, and a few that should have had [canonicalization](/questions/tagged/canonicalization).  I've flagged for a moderator to create the synonym, and they have.  I'll also go through the [canonicalization](/questions/tagged/canonicalization) questions and convert those that should be to [canonical-link](/questions/tagged/canonical-link).