# A Bounty Reputation Bug Possibly

Tags: discussion, support, bounties

So there was an excellent question over on Stack Overflow, so I answered the question.  Also several other people answered as well.  The question had very good responses.  So we all answered in attempt to get his *bounty*.

Well initially my question took the *bounty* but he didn't mark an answer.  So I thought, I'll offer some of my rep to see if we can find this guy the proper answer.  Well, my bounty got a lot more answers.

Well, I was out of town and I came back today.  The *Grace Period* had ended.  So I couldn't issue a *bounty*.  That isn't a big deal- as it is supposed to go to the person with the highest marked *answer*.

This is where it gets really odd.

It gave me a box that said:

> ```
> Your grace period has ended please enter your bounty as soon as possible.
> ```

So I was going to select a answer for the rewards; then all the selections vanished and I couldn't award my bounty.  So I'm assuming it went to automatically assign the bounty.  The problem is, my answer took the lead.

So because it was my bounty and I had already one bounty, and it went to assign it automatically to me my own bounty the reputation just vanished.

Essentially it is in this limbo state now, I don't have the reputation- no one can be awarded it just vanished.

Is this a bug?  Now what do I do?

Comment: Bounties only apply automatically to answers entered *after* the bounty was started, so you cannot have gotten your own bounty.

Comment: I understand that, there were more *answers* after I started the bounty; but it didn't award to them it just simply vanished.

Comment: Did any of those answers get 2 or more upvotes?

Comment: Presumably it is this question: [Why Getting Http Request and Response too late](http://stackoverflow.com/q/15415437)

Comment: Yeah, it is that question. And I believe one of them got four; if none did what would happen?

Comment: Before or after the bounty grace period had ended? If none had made 2 or more upvotes by the time the bounty had ended the bounty would not be awarded

Comment: Both, I'm slightly confused cause I see it took the 100 rep from me but I don't see it awarded to anyone.

Comment: When did the bounty expire?

Comment: Earlier today. Around 11 AM Pacific Standard.

Comment: Ah! That would explain it.  Thank you Martijin, I just didn't want someone to get shafted.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Looking at the [edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15415437/revisions) no winning answer was found so the bounty was not awarded.

The [question timeline](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15415437/timeline) shows that the only answers that got enough upvotes were already posted **before** you set the bounty on March 28th.

Only answers posted *after* the bounty and with at least 2 upvotes are eligable for automatic assignment, no such answers were posted. The answers by users `user2077488` and `user209737` were the only new answers and they didn't gain any votes.

Bounties are there to promote a question, and here it did that job admirably. The fact that the bounty can also be awarded to a specific answer is a nice extra for the answerer, but not a given.

Comment: That makes sense, so the bounty is lost then since the only ones after my initial post of the bounty didn't qualify.

Answer (score 5):

You started the "reward existing answer" bounty on March 28. The only two answers that were posted since then have 0 scores and aren't eligible for the automatic award.

If you missed the grace period and didn't award the bounty yourself, it is unfortunately lost and cannot be awarded anymore. You can see confirmation of this from the [revision history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/15415437/revisions):

> Bounty Ended with no winning answer by Community♦